# How to see code of running EC2 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've recently joined in a project. They asked me to develop a particular module so I did. Now I need to integrate it with the system. They gave me AWS login credentials for the integration purpose. I'm new to AWS and I don't wanna sound dumb to them by asking where's the code. I saw that there's an EC2 instance running but I see no option to see code there. So can you please let me know where can I see the code of running EC2 instance?

Answer (score 3):

Never feel dumb about asking questions on your team. It's much better to ask questions and seek clarification, rather than assume and waste your time and theirs.

So if your team is tasking you with integrating a module you've built with something running on EC2, they probably have an API of some sorta to integrate. They likely aren't expecting you to go to EC2 and view code or decompile DLLs to view source code.

However, to potentially answer your question if your EC2 instance is running some sort of application that has DLLs, you can download those and decompile them using various tools to view the actual source code. YOu would of course need the keypair to access the EC2 instances so you'd have to get that first.

I would just ask someone on your team how to integrate with the system running on EC2. They likely have the source code stored somewhere in a repository.